# Sort list of dict with random exception (without sorting)

Tags: python, json, list, sorting, quicksort

I have a list of dictionaries, I sort it by a certain parameter (EPС). Now I need to randomly select from this list 20-30% of dictionaries that do not need to be sorted. So it should be sort 1-2-3-4-5 by EPC, and then 20-30% of objects selected at random, and then the rest sorted by EPC.

> For example: We have 10 records, take 30% (3 records) randomly (before
> sorting), then sort the rest of 7, then place 3 randomly selected
> records in the n-place of sorted (for example in the middle of the
> sorted list)

My list example

```
OFFERS = [
   {
      "id":"43136bb6-c5e5-4d34-acff-605ff64e4d85",
      "impressions":2000,
      "clicks":481,
      "leads":1,
      "payout":1768,
      "epc":3
   },
   {
      "id":"f7025432-e7c3-414a-b817-833c0a520c69",
      "impressions":3241,
      "clicks":467,
      "leads":48,
      "payout":2486,
      "epc":255
   },
   {
      "id":"53c567be-86aa-4eb1-8448-2a701bc9bff0",
      "impressions":1083,
      "clicks":588,
      "leads":19,
      "payout":3195,
      "epc":103
   },
   {
      "id":"0d45d6cd-ead9-407c-aa13-3e9e9ed2898d",
      "impressions":2670,
      "clicks":569,
      "leads":24,
      "payout":2801,
      "epc":118
   },
   {
      "id":"fd470c97-a9c2-4171-8327-a7e2151a6d76",
      "impressions":3975,
      "clicks":592,
      "leads":39,
      "payout":2410,
      "epc":158
   },
   {
      "id":"a8f8b25a-b52b-4d76-b3e0-0c517d75d9dd",
      "impressions":1917,
      "clicks":317,
      "leads":5,
      "payout":3443,
      "epc":54
   },
   {
      "id":"1ce96ecc-b034-4809-a990-c2279cd78e66",
      "impressions":3531,
      "clicks":411,
      "leads":22,
      "payout":1681,
      "epc":89
   },
   {
      "id":"d634df9b-5dd2-484c-8298-1788f66891df",
      "impressions":2959,
      "clicks":489,
      "leads":19,
      "payout":1106,
      "epc":42
   },
   {
      "id":"1169d632-25f2-4241-a6e5-37ba94469d0e",
      "impressions":2201,
      "clicks":566,
      "leads":16,
      "payout":1773,
      "epc":50
   },
   {
      "id":"683842d4-e212-4f66-a729-2e70ef0c2837",
      "impressions":3875,
      "clicks":511,
      "leads":49,
      "payout":3289,
      "epc":315
   },
   {
      "id":"fbe95639-e03d-4a65-89b8-c7c21628b744",
      "impressions":4070,
      "clicks":409,
      "leads":61,
      "payout":1965,
      "epc":293
   },
   {
      "id":"54f4dfa5-dbd5-439f-a6a6-534214a60b45",
      "impressions":2728,
      "clicks":223,
      "leads":15,
      "payout":2906,
      "epc":195
   },
   {
      "id":"e751efb9-ad53-4635-89db-b7eee4b9c586",
      "impressions":2005,
      "clicks":506,
      "leads":2,
      "payout":1457,
      "epc":5
   },
   {
      "id":"467cbed3-121c-4c8e-a094-d43b371a677f",
      "impressions":3320,
      "clicks":286,
      "leads":45,
      "payout":3136,
      "epc":493
   },
   {
      "id":"8d726f55-4570-4827-99b4-909ebd9dd166",
      "impressions":3913,
      "clicks":588,
      "leads":20,
      "payout":3436,
      "epc":116
   }
]
```

Now im sorting by epc

```
sorted_data = sorted(OFFERS, key=lambda d: d['epc'], reverse=True)
```

Can someone help with the implementation of random selection without sorting?

Comment: I don't understand the goal. Do you want the first 5 sorted, then 20-30% in any random order, then the rest sorted? Sorting the entire list satisfies that; the sorted order is just as likely to be chosen at random as any other order.

Comment: We have 10 records, take 30% (3 records) randomly (before sorting), then sort the rest of 7, then place 3 randomly selected records in the n-place of sorted (for example in the middle of the sorted list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import random

# select N offers:
N = int(len(OFFERS) * 0.3)
selected = list(random.sample(range(len(OFFERS)), N))

# sort the remaining by EPC
out = sorted(
    [o for i, o in enumerate(OFFERS) if i not in selected],
    key=lambda k: k["epc"],
    reverse=True,
)

# put selected in some place (in the middle):
place = len(out) // 2
for s in selected:
    out.insert(place, OFFERS[s])

print(out)
```

Prints (for example):

```py
[
    {
        "id": "467cbed3-121c-4c8e-a094-d43b371a677f",
        "impressions": 3320,
        "clicks": 286,
        "leads": 45,
        "payout": 3136,
        "epc": 493,
    },
    {
        "id": "54f4dfa5-dbd5-439f-a6a6-534214a60b45",
        "impressions": 2728,
        "clicks": 223,
        "leads": 15,
        "payout": 2906,
        "epc": 195,
    },
    {
        "id": "fd470c97-a9c2-4171-8327-a7e2151a6d76",
        "impressions": 3975,
        "clicks": 592,
        "leads": 39,
        "payout": 2410,
        "epc": 158,
    },
    {
        "id": "0d45d6cd-ead9-407c-aa13-3e9e9ed2898d",
        "impressions": 2670,
        "clicks": 569,
        "leads": 24,
        "payout": 2801,
        "epc": 118,
    },
    {
        "id": "8d726f55-4570-4827-99b4-909ebd9dd166",
        "impressions": 3913,
        "clicks": 588,
        "leads": 20,
        "payout": 3436,
        "epc": 116,
    },
    {
        "id": "683842d4-e212-4f66-a729-2e70ef0c2837",
        "impressions": 3875,
        "clicks": 511,
        "leads": 49,
        "payout": 3289,
        "epc": 315,
    },
    {
        "id": "f7025432-e7c3-414a-b817-833c0a520c69",
        "impressions": 3241,
        "clicks": 467,
        "leads": 48,
        "payout": 2486,
        "epc": 255,
    },
    {
        "id": "a8f8b25a-b52b-4d76-b3e0-0c517d75d9dd",
        "impressions": 1917,
        "clicks": 317,
        "leads": 5,
        "payout": 3443,
        "epc": 54,
    },
    {
        "id": "fbe95639-e03d-4a65-89b8-c7c21628b744",
        "impressions": 4070,
        "clicks": 409,
        "leads": 61,
        "payout": 1965,
        "epc": 293,
    },
    {
        "id": "53c567be-86aa-4eb1-8448-2a701bc9bff0",
        "impressions": 1083,
        "clicks": 588,
        "leads": 19,
        "payout": 3195,
        "epc": 103,
    },
    {
        "id": "1ce96ecc-b034-4809-a990-c2279cd78e66",
        "impressions": 3531,
        "clicks": 411,
        "leads": 22,
        "payout": 1681,
        "epc": 89,
    },
    {
        "id": "1169d632-25f2-4241-a6e5-37ba94469d0e",
        "impressions": 2201,
        "clicks": 566,
        "leads": 16,
        "payout": 1773,
        "epc": 50,
    },
    {
        "id": "d634df9b-5dd2-484c-8298-1788f66891df",
        "impressions": 2959,
        "clicks": 489,
        "leads": 19,
        "payout": 1106,
        "epc": 42,
    },
    {
        "id": "e751efb9-ad53-4635-89db-b7eee4b9c586",
        "impressions": 2005,
        "clicks": 506,
        "leads": 2,
        "payout": 1457,
        "epc": 5,
    },
    {
        "id": "43136bb6-c5e5-4d34-acff-605ff64e4d85",
        "impressions": 2000,
        "clicks": 481,
        "leads": 1,
        "payout": 1768,
        "epc": 3,
    },
]
```